# Run Firefox with Apache (www-data) on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Trying to run FireFox through apache (php script)
I recieve the following error

```
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :0.0
```

I tried login with www-data through console and run it - got the same result
I tried to set the "DISPLAY" variable to a different display with no success

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the DISPLAY environment variable to a X window display and then you can run the same. But on the X window display you need to run xhost + to allow remote systems to display on the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that Firefox need the X environment set up(Graphic interface) and through a php script or from console as www-data you don't have the X environment. That is the error it's showing.

Comment: You can't. If you need want to launch firefox you need to be logged in as a user who has Graphic Interface. What do you need firefox for?